# State channels in IOTA

Tags: asktheexperts

I'm looking to implement an application like video streaming, in which a user can pay at max a price X depending on how much of the video he has watched. I think this logic is implemented in Bitcoin by state channels. Is there a similar mechanism in IOTA?

Comment: We used to have flash channels for something like this. There is a streaming payment protocol but it's not exactly implemented: https://anrg.usc.edu/www/papers/streamingDataPaymentProtocol_2018.pdf

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just managed to read the paper. In the paper I see some king of period payments which are recorded. I don't see any ensurance (lock of money lets say) for any of the parties, like in state channels. Do I miss something?